# How to install and use angularjs on ubuntu18.04?

Tags: server, javascript, project-management

Can anyone share me how can I use **angularjs** latest version. I want to do **project on angularjs**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with installing corresponding package (see search results [on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=angularjs)):

```
sudo apt install libjs-angularjs
```

This package:

> lets you write client-side web applications as if you had a smarter browser